# How to identify and make a link out of '@' in user comments like they do on Youtube

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube

I want to look into making functionality like Youtube has on their website when a user types in a comment and if they have something like '@username' the system recognizes the '@' sign and makes a link to the username's comments.  I'm developing using Rails 3 but any information regarding about the logic required for this feature would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:  Additonal question:  Where's the best place to put the logic for this?  I would feel like the controller would be so if a client doesn't have javascript it'll still work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure there are multiple (and even better) ways of doing this. How I did it was -

A function to parse the input string: I wrote a helper function -

1. It traversed every word in the post and for all words starting with an '@'
2. For every such word it checked if the user existed in the application.
3. If yes then replace the word with a link to the user profile.
4. Write the new post (one with the links) to the database.

   ```
   def mention_users_and_tags(post)
       post_with_user_links = ""
       words = post.message.split
       words.each do |word|
           if word[0] =~ /^@.*/ and word.length > 1
               if extract_user_if_exists(word[1,word.length-1])
                   post_with_user_links << "#{link_to "#{word}", :controller => "users", :action => "show", :id => @mentioned_user.id} "
               else
                   post_with_user_links << word << " "
               end
           end
       end
   end
   ```

EDIT - I think this method should be written in the model and called in the controller. This was the first time I was coding in rails, so I wasn't very sure where everything goes and I wrote this as a helper function. But now I know all business logic goes in the Model. Since mentioning users in posts can be considered part of the business logic, I'd write a function for it in the model.

Comment: I thought about something like this, wasn't sure if there was a better method.  I'm going to hold off a bit before I accept the answer to try and get more feedback.  Thanks for the help

Comment: I think this method should be written in the model and called in the controller. This was the first time I was coding in rails, so I wasn't very sure where everything goes and I wrote this as a helper function. But now I know all business logic goes in the Model. Since mentioning users in posts can be considered part of the business logic, I'd write a function for it in the model.

Comment: Thanks.  You won't be able to use link_to as the helper isn't included in the model unless you do some fancy stuff which is generally not recommended I've heard.  Solution: write the HTML out